# Анимация движения не работает. Unity, C #

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не так давно начал изучать Unity и при анимации столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
При перемещении влево, вправо, персонаж не начинает анимацию ходьбы, а продолжается анимация покоя. Если сделать прыжок, то ходит как надо.

```
public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed;
    public float jump;
    public Transform GroundCheck;
    bool isGrounded;
    Animator anim;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        CheckGround();
    
        Jump();
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")== 0 && (isGrounded))
        {
            anim.SetInteger("State", 1); // анимация покоя
        }
        else
        {
            Flip();
            if (isGrounded)
                anim.SetInteger("State", 2);// анимация движения 
        }


    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {


    } void Flip()

    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0); // флип  
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, rb.velocity.y);// передвижение 



    }

    void CheckGround()
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(GroundCheck.position, 0.2f); // проверка ног/соприкосновение с землей 
        isGrounded = colliders.Length > 1;
        if (!isGrounded)
            anim.SetInteger("State", 3);
    }
    void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * jump, ForceMode2D.Impulse); // прыжок
    }

 }
```

Убирал задержку между переходами в аниматоре. Can Transition To Self выключен. [image: Скриншот Аниматора]

Comment: А вы знаете, что вместо SetInteger() с непонятной нумерацией State'ов можно использовать функцию [Animator.Play()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html), просто указав назавание анимации первым параметром? Мне кажется в вашем случае это будет даже легче.